# Transfer matlab code to c#, serialport problems

Tags: c#, matlab, encoding, serial-port

I have a few problems regarding matlab and c#. What I want to do is to bring a certain piece of code I have from matlab to c#. The problem is whenever I read the serialport, the data in matlab is fine and everything works as intended, but c# just completely messes it up and I do not know why.

Regarding that problem here are a few of the code snippets, which I think matter and my 'translations' for c#:

This is my code to open the serialport. I know the if close if there is any data on the port is missing, but that should not be a concern as the data is always there in my case.

MATLAB:

```
if ~isempty (instrfind)
    fclose (instrfind);
end
s = serial('COMPort4',...
    'BaudRate', 56000,...
    'Parity', 'none',...
    'DataBits', 8,...
    'StopBits', 1,...
    'InputBufferSize', 65552,...
    'OutputBufferSize', 32768,...
    'Terminator','CR',...
    'Timeout', 2);
fopen(s);
```

C#:

```
SerialPort radarCom = new SerialPort("COM4", 56000,  Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
radarCom.WriteBufferSize = 16384;
radarCom.ReadBufferSize = 32768;
radarCom.ReadTimeout = 2;
radarCom.WriteTimeout = 2;
Console.Out.NewLine = "\r";
radarCom.Open();
```

Next I have certain commands to communicate with the controller via serialport
where certain variables are used. Here is a command where i send the same command via serialport if I did not do something wrong:

MATLAB:

```
Ndiv=['set_Ndiv ',num2str(PLL_22)]
fprintf(s,Ndiv);
```

C#:

```
string Ndiv =  "set_Ndiv "+ Convert.ToString(PLL_22) ;
radarCom.WriteLine(Ndiv);
```

After that I read the data from the serial port. However the result in matlab are a lot of numbers like 32534, 31534 etc., but in c# i get a weird mix of ????332/u???"????????\u011??????"????*???? or something similiar. I guess u get the idea of what i mean. However, here is the code how I read the serialport:

Matlab:

```
for n = 1:10000
    fprintf(s,'go');
    data= fread(s,100,'uint16');
end
```

C#:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10000; i++)
{
    radarCom.WriteLine("go");

    if (radarCom.BytesToRead != -1)
    {
        var data = radarCom.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me. I think the problem lies within the last read command in matlab and I do not know how to properly translate it into c#.

Comment: Interesting Baud rate, I've always used the Baud Rate listed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd187599.aspx

Comment: Seems you have problems with encoding. Try to read bytes manually and then decode them.

Comment: Hi i do not know how exactly that works. Do you have a utorial or guide how this is be done or what encoding exactly is?